# How to solve error related to overwriting file in Fortran?

Tags: fortran

I have the following code:

```
if ((mod(kk,NINT(1/DT)).eq.0).or.((kk.eq.1).and.(count.eq.0))) then
             ! Write out .CON file
             if ((kk.eq.1).and.(count.eq.0))then                                                                                                                                                                                              
    9999        FORMAT(1X,F9.2,1X,F9.3,1X,F9.3,1X,F9.3,1X,F9.3,1X,F9.3,1X,F9.3,1X,F9.3,3E16.1)                
                open(9,file=NAME_CON,status='new',position='append')                                                                                                                                                                         
                WRITE(9,9999) 
             else  
                open(9,file=NAME_CON,status='old',position='append')
             end if
             WRITE(9,9999) &
             TIME, &
             sum(H(:,:,3), (H(:,:,3).gt.0))*DX*DY/1000000000, &
             sum(G(:,:), (H(:,:,3).gt.0)) / sum(mask, (H(:,:,3).gt.0)), &
             sum(mask, (H(:,:,3).gt.0))*DX*DY/1000000, &
             maxval(H(:, :, 3)), &
             maxval(sqrt(VY(:,:,1)*VY(:,:,1)+VX(:,:,1)*VX(:,:,1))), &
             rmse, &
             ANEWG, &
             ASL
             close(9)
end if
```

However, when I run the script the following error occurs on Line 603 (open(9,file=NAME_CON,status='new',position='append') ):

```
forrtl: severe (10): cannot overwrite existing file, unit 9, file /theia/home/bxl/101/vsc10101/3Dmod/model/workdir/CON25
```

Can anyone help to solve this error as I don't know why it is occurring? Thanks.

Comment: maybe use in a;ll cases `status="unknown"` and in case of your `old ` leave `position='append'` and in case of `new use `position='rewind'`. Also have a look at the `INQUIRE` statement  to check whether or not a file exists.

Comment: How to correctly solve the error depends on the behaviour you want. Do you want to replace the file in the first iteration, or append to an existing file (if one exists). Either way, why do you close the file just to reopen it next time around (rather than flushing)?

Comment: @francescalus Hi, I want to append to an existing file so that in each iteration a new row is added with the variables that I stated.